# Cat is screeching terrified of me; screaming, hissing and claws out and I cant go near him

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, psychology

We have a sphynx who is 2 years old and never had problems with our dogs. Today, our dog scared him so bad after the cat jumped on her (accidentally trying to get onto my chair; the dog turned around and jumped and got scared too (they scared each other)) that now the sphynx won't come out, he is absolutely **screeching** his head off if you go anywhere near his space and hisses and swats; a noise I have **never** heard him make before. He's been alone for six hours; we left the house, put the dogs outside, and came back and he is still doing it.

I don't know what to do I am terrified he will never be the same. I have offered food he won't eat, etc. What do I do? I am having a panic attack and meltdown I am just so sad and heartbroken and love my nakkid so much I wouldn't want him to be scared in his own home; where he never was before.

Comment: First thing is for you to calm down. Second is for you to give him time to calm down without you or the dog pestering him. Leave food and water for him, make sure he has clear access to the litter box, and let him decide when he's ready to deal with the world again.

Comment: Short-term memory for one-time events like this is said to be around 15 hours for cats, you should try giving the cat some space for this time and avoid any involuntary contact. Since he already retreated to his space, it might be a good idea to provide water and his litterbox there as well so he doesn't need to come out if he does not want to.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others, kitty needs some quite alone space and time. It's unlikely that this will change your cat. He may have attitude with the dogs for a little while though. Also you could put some calming treats near him. However, there's a pretty good chance that he won't want to eat anything at all until he feels the area is safe again. There's also a plug-in aroma thing (like a glade type of product) called Feliway (spelling might not be right) that is made of cats' pheromones and it's supposed to calm cats down. Personally, when my cats are stressed I usually make sure they are left alone until they come to me, and I also use catnip with silvervine in it to just relax them and give them a good buzz. I just put like a teaspoon of it on dish and then just put it near them.